# How can you categorize your DE by email domain using SFMC Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query, dataextensions

I have a Data Extension(s) that I would like to find the amount of gmail email domains it contains. Would using a query be the best way to find this data or is there a different feature in the SFMC UI that I can use?

Example
DE 1
DE 2
DE 3

I would like to find the total amount of `example@gmail.com` domains are within DE 1, 2, & 3.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a [Query Activity](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) would be best.  You'd have to know the names of all of your Data Extensions.

A simple query like this would do the trick:

```
select
x.emailAddress
, count(*) counter
from (
  select emailAddress from DE1 
  union all
  select emailAddress from DE2
  union all
  select emailAddress from DE3
) x
where x.emailAddress like '%@gmail.com'
group by x.emailAddress
```

...writing to a Data Extension with these columns:

```
EmailAddress, EmailAddress
Counter, Number
```